# in jspdf-autotable header arabic text breaking

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

```
 document.autoTable({
      head,
      body,
      startY: XX,
      styles: { lineColor: '#c7c7c7', lineWidth: 0, cellPadding: 2, font: 'Helvetica' },
      headStyles: { fillColor: '#ffffff', textColor: '#333333', font: 'Helvetica' },
      bodyStyles: { fillColor: '#f5f5f5', textColor: '#333333', fontSize: 7, lineColor: '#c7c7c7', lineWidth: 0 }
    });

head am passing as below:
const head = [{
        content: "طيران الإمارات",
        styles: { valign: 'centre', cellPadding: {top: 3}, fontSize: 9, fontStyle: 'bold', cellWidth: 110.6 },
      },
      {
        content: 'Miles',
        styles: { fontSize: 9, fontStyle: 'normal', valign: 'centre', cellWidth: 35 },
      },
      {
        content: 'Tier Miles',
        styles: { fontSize: 9, fontStyle: 'normal', valign: 'centre', cellWidth: 35 },
      }
      ];
```

with **Helvetica** Font, Head Text showing as special characters.
[Special Characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTiyL.jpg)

With Custom font Its showing in Arabic but word is breaking
I have passed as header this "طيران الإمارات" but in pdf its showing as this طير لإما  [Breaking word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx6zW.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please add some more information so that it is easier for others to help you. This article shows more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`headStyles: { fillColor: '#bde4d1', textColor: '#333333' , fontStyle: 'Amiri' }`

you have to add `fontStyle` in headStyles object

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Its working with Amiri font.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to google fonts and download [Amiri font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Amiri?selection.family=Great%20Vibes&query=amiri) ( I have tried other Arabic fonts but they did not work for some reason).
2. Go to [this converter tool](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html) to convert your font to base64 and download the generated JavaScript file (When converting your Amiri font, upload one *.ttf* file per time and not the full *.zip* folder, otherwise you will get an error. If you want to add more font variants upload and add them separately).
3. Go to your project and import the downloaded file (or add the script tag manually if you do not use modules).

```js
import "./fonts/Amiri";

// .... here goes your code working with the table.
```

4. If you use [jspdf-autotable library](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable) add the following code to its configs:

```js
const jsPDFDoc = new jsPDF();

jsPDFDoc.autoTable({
  html: "#my-table",
  useCss: true,
  theme: "grid",
  headStyles: { font: "Amiri" }, // For Arabic text in the table head
  bodyStyles: { font: "Amiri" }, // For Arabic text in the table body
});
```

Full example with autotable would look like this:

```js
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import "jspdf-autotable";
import "../../../fonts/Amiri";

const jsPDFDoc = new jsPDF();

jsPDFDoc.autoTable({
  html: "#my-table",
  useCss: true,
  theme: "grid",
  headStyles: { font: "Amiri" },
  bodyStyles: { font: "Amiri" },
});
```