# Using arabic font in jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I want to render html template to pdf file but my template include arabic characters and jspdf can't encode and keeps printing numbers instead of the actual text i tried setting lang to ar but that didn't work too does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Have you tried to save as an image then convert to PDF?

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71813608/14749084) if you still have a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I have seen so far about jsPDF you will have to select a font that includes all characters for your language.

I think this might help you: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1823

see the oficial documentation too: http://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#setFont